# C++ Out of Range Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Okay so I keep getting this error when I try to run my code and can't figure out how to fix it.
(Unhandled exception at 0x75195608 in hw6.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0101F850.)\
I have included my source code below. Also the file that I am reading from is not long at all so I don’t think that’s the problem.

```
int main() {

    //Initializes all of the variables, strings,boolean, and vectors
    ifstream inFS;
    int count = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int location = 0;
    char ch;
    bool marker = 0;
    string filename = "hw6-Fall2017.txt";
    string list = "ABCDEFGHIJKEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    vector<int> locations;
    vector<int> find_Locations;
    vector<char> notFound;
    vector<char> Found;

    //Iterates through the file searching for each of the characters
    while (count <= 62) {
        inFS.open(filename);
        if (!inFS.is_open()) {
            cout << "Could not open the file: " << filename << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        while (inFS.get(ch) && marker == 0) {
            location++;
            if (ch == list[i]) {
                marker = 1;
            }
        }
        inFS.close();
        //Sets characters not found to have a location of 0
        if (marker == 0) {
            location = 0;
        }
        locations.push_back(location);
        marker = 0;
        location = 0;
        i++;
        count++;
    }

    //Creates a table printing out the characters and their susequent locations
    for (i = 0;i < list.size();i++) {
        if (locations.at(i) == 0) {
            cout << list[i] << " " << setw(6) << "NotFnd"<< " ";
            notFound.push_back(list[i]);
        }
        else {
            cout << list[i] << " " << setw(6) << locations.at(i) << " ";
            find_Locations.push_back(locations.at(i));
        }
        j++;
        if (j == 5) {
            cout << endl;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    //Sorts the characters in the order that they were found
    sort(find_Locations.begin(), find_Locations.end());
    for (i = 0;i < find_Locations.size();i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < locations.size();j++) {
            if (find_Locations.at(i) == locations.at(j) && marker == 0) {
                Found.push_back(list[j]);
                j = locations.size();
            }
        }
    }

    count = 0;
    j = 0;

    //Creates a table printing out the characters in the oreder they were found
    //in the text file along with their locations.  Characters not found are
    //displayed first with a location of "NotFnd".
    for (i = 0;i < (Found.size() + notFound.size());i++) {
        if (i < Found.size()) {
            cout << Found.at(i) << " " << setw(6) << find_Locations.at(i)<< " ";
        }
        else {
            cout << notFound.at(j) << " " << setw(6) << "NotFnd" << " ";
            j++;
        }
        count++;
        if (count == 5) {
            cout << endl;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: The output stopped working around the 58th iteration @user0042

Comment: Then set a conditional breakpoint to stop at the 56th or 57th iteration and single step from there..

Comment: Although where it breaks you can go up the callstack to at least understand what array access is out of bounds.

Comment: How would I do that?? @drescherjm

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/10/11/conditional-breakpoints/

Comment: I know you already sent the link but do you see any errors with my code that could be causing a memory leak?? @drescherjm

Comment: A memory leak has nothing to do with the error. The error is out of bounds access.

Comment: ***do you see any errors with my code that could be causing a memory*** I am not that great at debugging a program in my head..

Comment: `for (i = 0;i < (Found.size() + notFound.size());i++) {` I am not sure why you are writing this loop like this. Although I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not easy to find with code review.

But this line looks nice in itself

```
string list = "ABCDEFGHIJKEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

but together with this

```
while (count <= 62) {
```

It looks suspicious, I think it should have been

```
while (count < list.size()) { // 2*26+10==62
```

An "Off by one error" which could cause a problem here

```
for (i = 0;i < find_Locations.size();i++) {
    for (j = 0;j < locations.size();j++) {
        if (find_Locations.at(i) == locations.at(j) && marker == 0) {
            Found.push_back(list[j]); // <--- if J>=list.size()
            j = locations.size();
        }
    }
}
```

And a potential crash at the marked line.

But the real error is here

```
         Found.push_back(list[j]); // j should have been i
```

Which should cause a crash at

```
        cout << Found.at(i) << " " << setw(6) << find_Locations.at(i)<< " ";
```